# How to show log in custom installer in wix

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I am making a custom installer in wix. This will have multiple steps for completing the even. Everything is working fine. Now I want the show some message line.

```
Step 1 starting
step 1 Running...
Step 1 Completed
Step 2 Starting
Step 2 Aborted. File missing.
Step 3 Starting
```

Which control will be suitable? Edit control? Please help with code for custom action so that I can append message from `C#` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Windows Installer doesn't provide a built-in mechanism to show UI like that. To get that level of customization, you'll need to create an [ExternalUIHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Essentially, you create an executable that registers to get messages from the Windows Installer then kicks off the install and draws UI the way you want. As you might guess, it takes quite a bit of work.

DTF in the WiX toolset provides a lot of wrappers for the MSI functions you'll need to call to get it all working. See the `SetExternalUI` method on the `Installer` class in the `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller` namespace to get started.

Good luck! Lots of work ahead.